# Settings: Missing automatic suspend/sleep option (terminal workaround possible?)

Tags: suspend, power-management, 22.04, settings

I can't setup the time until how much idle-time the device should go suspend (go to sleep) **automatically**, the whole option is missing.

---

#### Issue

Automatic suspend/sleep option missing in `power panel` of the **Settings-App**. (see image 1)

---

#### Question:

- Does someone knows a fix?
- Or how I could setup **automatic sleep/suspend** via terminal?

---

#### Setup

- **OS**: `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`
- **Device**: `Mac Mini Late 2014`

---

#### Manual Suspend/sleep itself works:

- I can suspend my device via via **hardware-power button** or the **suspend/sleep-button** in the top right corner of the gnome-desktop menu (see image 2).
- The device suspends/sleeps perfectly, indicator on device shows sleep state and wakes up as soon WOL (wake-on-lan) package comes in.

My wish is to put the device into sleep/suspend if it doesn't got used (idle) for 60 minutes.

---

#### Image 1

[image: Settings App - Power panel - Missing option]

#### Image 2

[image: Gnome Desktop - Top right corner - Sleep/Suspend button]

Comment: Are you using a remote tool? This Option doesn't show up, when you're using a remote client. Atleast that was my problem.

Comment: @botnoob: Yes it was a headless Mac, connected via RDP with the xRDP server on the linux-machine. But still strange why they hide it on headless-machines (remote devices), especially these should be able to go to sleep after to much idle.